# Sum a row only if there an ID correspondence

Tags: r, database, sum

I trying to solve the following issue by using R:

Suppose I have two datasets:

Dataset 1(I call it long):

[image]

where ID stands for the firm's identity and stock is the number of employees at the end of 2014.

Dataset 2 (I call it short):

[image]

ID stands for the firm's identity (as long's dataset) and flow is the net hiring in 2015

The idea is to augment the stock (firm's size in Dec 2014) with the flow that occurred in 2015. For some firms (firms are identified by an ID number) there is no change in their size. This means that the rows of the short dataset are lower than those of the long dataset.
What I shall get is something like this

[image]

Basically, I should find a way to sum the flow to stock only if there is correspondence with the ID.

I tried to do the following but the third (new) dataset I create drops the rows where there is no ID correspondence.

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
short = read_excel("short.xlsx")
long=read_excel("long.xlsx")
data_new=rbindlist(list(short, long), fill = TRUE)[,lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = T) , id]
```

Comment: data |> group(id) |> mutate( stock-2015 = sum(stock-2014+flow))

Comment: Thanks for yr reply. Unfortunately, It does not work in R

Comment: This expects tidy input data.  i am pretty sure R is not the problem here but the data

Comment: Let me rephrase the question, maybe it was not clear, and I'm going to add my coding attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the two datasets together, then `group_by` the `id` column, then `sum` the `stock` column (with `flow` renamed to `stock`).

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(long_dat, short_dat %>% rename("stock" = "flow")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(stock = sum(stock))
```

#### Output

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 2
     id stock
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    83
2     4     6
3    13     5
4    16     9
5    18     7
6    27     7
```

#### Data

```r
long_dat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 4, 13, 16, 18, 27), stock = c(82, 6, 5, 9, 7, 6))
short_dat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 27), flow = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to match the rows by id's. There are lots of ways to do that, one of them is using join functions.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(id1 = c(1,18, rep(NA, 4)),
              flow = c(7,1, rep(NA, 4)),
              id2 = c(1,4,13,16,18,27),
              `stock-2014` = c(82,6,5,9,7,6))


right_join(df1 %>% select(c(id1, flow)) %>% na.omit(), #flow df
           df1 %>% select(c(id2, `stock-2014`)), #stock df
           by = c("id1" = "id2")) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% #replace NA's with 0
  mutate(`stock-2015` = `stock-2014` + flow)
```

**Edit:**

As you`ve edited your answer, you seem to already have separated datasets, then is even easier:

```
short <- tibble(id = c(1,18),
                flow = c(7,1))
long <- tibble(id = c(1,4,13,16,18,27),
               `stock-2014` = c(82,6,5,9,7,6))

right_join(short, long, by = "id") %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  mutate(`stock-2015` = `stock-2014` + flow)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get the following error "could not find function "%>%". Pls, note I want to match the two datasets by ID, but if the ID in the short dataset is not there, I have to still add the row from the long dataset.  Pls, consider the third table I added as the outcome I'm looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: I forgot to add, this answer needs `library(dplyr)`. Check my edit!